# smtp.js The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Tags: javascript, html, email, smtp, html-email

I have tried a lot of ways to fix this script but it keep alert me only just

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

```
function sendEmail() {
    var elmail = document.getElementById('Email-Register-name').value;
    var elmailw = document.getElementById('Email-Register-domain').value;
    console.log(elmail+"@"+elmailw)
        Email.send({
            Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
            Username : "my mail",
            Password : "pw",
            To : elmail+'@'+elmailw,
            From : "my domain",
            Subject : "Verification Email from tab the_dev",
            Body : "<html><h2>Header</h2><strong>Bold text</strong><br></br><em>Italic</em></html>"
}).then(
        message => alert(message)
    )
};
```

I tried to find from all code community to fix that.

I tried like

- Swap the position of 'To' and 'From'
- Change From's value to email

etc...., but nothing makes it work.

Do you guys have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Double check both To and From and see if its value is a valid email address.

```
From : "my domain",
```

This one does not seems to be a valid email address.

Comment: i tried that way too